# Windows SEH - What exactly is __except_handler3?

Tags: windows, winapi, seh

My current understanding of SEH in windows is that when an exception occurs the OS uses the **FS:[0]**  register which contains the address of a _EXCEPTION_RECORD linked list which in turn has a plethora of functions that might or might not handle the exception. My question is, what does  **_except_handler3** have to do with all of this?

Comment: It is the C++ runtime function that implements the exception filter, it detects a C++ exception.  Specific to the Microsoft CRT, it uses the SEH plumbing to implement C++ exception handling.

Comment: *fs:[0]* is only for *x86*. and it containing pointer to `EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION_RECORD` (look in *winnt.h*) but not `EXCEPTION_RECORD`. the `_except_handler3` is have `PEXCEPTION_ROUTINE` type

Comment: [A Crash Course on the Depths of Win32™ Structured Exception Handling](http://bytepointer.com/resources/pietrek_crash_course_depths_of_win32_seh.htm). Doesn't have information on x64 code, but you appear to be learning about 32-bit code anyway, so that is a good read.